# Laravel, Eloquent: Fetch all entries from many-to-many relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have two tables linked by a pivot table (with a custom migration):

Interest table:

```
ID | label
```

Person table:

```
ID | label
```

PersonHasInterest table (custom migration):

```
InterestID | PersonID | notes
```

How can I get all records from the pivot table (with persons and interests joined in)? I don't want to get all interests of a person or all persons that have an interest but all entries (with joins) of the pivot table.

Comment: Define a model for the pivot table then call `PersonHasInterest::all()?`

Comment: but how can I define a model for a pivot?

Comment: The same way you do for a model, you can specify the table attribute

Comment: and what are the relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `Pivot` extends `Model` it is not possible to call the standard model functions on a `Pivot`-object. [Issue on Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17770).

What I came up is using the [DB-Facade](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Facades/DB.html) to execute a select statement, like so:

```
DB::table('person_has_interest')
    ->join('interest', 'person_has_interest.interest_id', '=', 'interest.id')
    ->join('person', 'person_has_interest.person_id', '=', 'person.id')
    ->get(); // further manipulation like select possible
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a pivot model like this:

```
<?php

...
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
...
class PersonHasInterest extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = '...'; // table name
}
```

Then use it: `PersonHasInterest::all();`

Comment: It's not possible.You cannot instantiate pivot with this approach. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17770